# redux/toolkit + Reactotron leads to jest error "TypeError: _reactotronConfig.default.createEnhancer is not a function"

Tags: react-native, redux-toolkit, reactotron

For quite some time, I've been trying to configure Reactotron and Redux Toolkit to avoid this annoying jest error: "TypeError: _reactotronConfig.default.createEnhancer is not a function," but without success. Reactotron is working properly; I can see the actions in the Reactotron desktop app, and so on. However, I can't get rid of this error. All suggestions are welcome. I have tried everything I found on the internet.Here is my setup:

reactotronConfig:

```
import Reactotron, { trackGlobalErrors, asyncStorage } from 'reactotron-react-native';
import { reactotronRedux } from 'reactotron-redux';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

Reactotron.configure({
  name: appName,
})
  .use(asyncStorage())
  .use(trackGlobalErrors())
  .useReactNative({
    storybook: true,
  })
  .use(reactotronRedux())
  .connect();
// .clear();

console.tron = Reactotron;

export default Reactotron;
```

reactotron-react-native.js (reactotron mock file):

```
export const Reactotron = {
  configure: () => Reactotron,
  useReactNative: () => Reactotron,
  asyncStorage: () => Reactotron,
  trackGlobalErrors: () => Reactotron,
  createEnhancer: () => Reactotron,
  use: () => Reactotron,
  connect: () => Reactotron,
  clear: () => Reactotron,
};

module.exports = Reactotron;
```

store:

```
import { configureStore, ThunkAction, Action } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import rootReducer from './reducers';
import Reactotron from '../../reactotronConfig';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: [],
  enhancers: [(Reactotron as any).createEnhancer!()],
});
```

The ERROR:
[image]

Comment: Oh, I see, you edited and now the error is in trying to create the Reactotron enhancer? Does your code work normally and you've only this issue in unit test code? I've never heard of Reactotron. Perhaps there is an issue with the Reactotron mock? Can you log the `Reactotron` reference in the unit test to verify what it has?

Comment: Yeah, i have logged it just before the store and it returns exactly what is in the mock file. This means that it is working for the test with the mocked data. As you can see above, the mocked object has createEnhancer, but for some reason for the test it is not recognising it. Appreciate your help! After the latest update of react native to 0.73+ they are suggesting reactotron as debugging tool.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to how i mocked createEnhancer function. It should be:

```
createEnhancer: () => jest.fn  <-- without the execution "()"
```